# Как отсортировать данные по колонке?

Tags: python, база-данных

Есть таблица с двумя колонками. Хочу отсортировать его по 1-й колонке, но проблема с типом данных. Сортировка по возрастанию. Если сделать колонку типом INT - то мой слеш потеряется. А если оставить как STRING - сортировка неправильная.

```
INDEX;TEXT
2;ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-2-ЖБ
20;ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-20-ЖБ
2/1;ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-2/1-ЖБ
21;ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-21-ЖБ
3;ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-3-ЖБ
```

Вот как должно получиться

```
INDEX;TEXT
2;ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-2-ЖБ
2/1;ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-2/1-ЖБ
3;ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-3-ЖБ
20;ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-20-ЖБ
21;ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-21-ЖБ
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При df:

```
  INDEX                   TEXT
0     2    ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-2-ЖБ
1    20   ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-20-ЖБ
2   2/1  ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-2/1-ЖБ
3    21   ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-21-ЖБ
4     3    ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-3-ЖБ
```

```
def func_(a):
    return  [int(x[0]) for x in a.str.split("/").tolist()]

df.sort_values(by="INDEX", key=func_, inplace=True)
```

получаем df:

```
  INDEX                   TEXT
0     2    ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-2-ЖБ
2   2/1  ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-2/1-ЖБ
4     3    ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-3-ЖБ
1    20   ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-20-ЖБ
3    21   ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-21-ЖБ
```

Answer (score 3):

попробуйте апдейтнуть поле вот так:

```
CREATE TABLE table(x varchar, y text);

INSERT INTO table VALUES('2', 'ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-2-ЖБ');
.
.
.

UPDATE table SET x = replace(x,'/','.');

SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY CAST(x AS INT);
```

output:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-2-ЖБ |
| 2.1 | ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-2/1-ЖБ |
| 3 | ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-3-ЖБ |
| 20 | ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-20-ЖБ |
| 21 | ТП 12-4/250-Ф2-21-ЖБ |

в SELECT можно прописать обратный replace чтобы вернуть изначально '.' на '/'

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается данный метод сортировки называется "[естественным](https://ru.qaz.wiki/wiki/Natural_sort_order)"

Для `pandas` есть возможность отсортировать так как нам нужно

```
import natsort as ns

df['index'] = pd.Categorical(df['index'], ordered=True, categories= ns.natsorted(df['index'].unique()))
```